# #ORA-01834 not a valid month

Tags: oracle

When I insert data into DB, it shows the messege "ORA-01834 not a valid month  ".
My inserted value is like '17-07-19 06.34.11', I Want to know what's the correct value

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Without specifics as to what your data looks like, the assumption is that you're trying to insert a row which has either a missing column or an invalid entry

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask, e.g.

```
insert into your_table (date_column)
  values (to_date('17-07-19 06.34.11', 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

---

By the way, switch to a 4-digit year ("2019" instead of "19").